# When does `make` apply the implicit rule `Makefile: Makefile.o`?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

In my working directory, there is a `makefile`, an empty `obj` folder and a `src` folder that contains `foo.c`. I have a simple rule that takes an object file, substitutes everything until the first slash with *src* and replaces the ending *.o* with *.c*.

**Example:** obj/foo.o --> src/foo.c

With the help of **MadScientist** (credits to him) I obtained the pattern rule below (Please do not propose easier rules --> I am aware of their existance, but only this rule demonstrates my problem):

```
OBJFILES=obj/foo.o
all: $(OBJFILES)
    @echo "all executed"

Y = $(shell echo $1 | sed -e 's,^[^\/]*,src,' -e 's,\.o$$,.c,')
.SECONDEXPANSION:
%.o: $$(call Y,$$@)
    @echo "OBJECTS executed for $@ - [$^]"

src/foo.c:
    @echo "Congrats"
```

Once I run the above makefile, I get a circular dependency:

```
xxxx@null:~/Desktop/experiment$ make
make: Circular src.o <- src dependency dropped.
OBJECTS executed for obj/foo.o - [src/foo.c]
all executed
```

The reason is found quickly: `Make` creates the implicit rule `Makefile: Makefile.o`, which triggers my pattern rule. Since `Makefile.o` does not contain a slash, `sed` evaluates to `src`. `Make` again applies the implicit rule `src:src.o` which eventually causes the circular dependency. This can be seen in the make output:

```
make --print-data-base | grep src
make: Circular src.o <- src dependency dropped.
OBJECTS executed for obj/foo.o - [src/foo.c]
Y = $(shell echo $1 | sed -e 's,^[^\/]*,src,' -e 's,\.o$$,.c,')
# src (device 64769, inode 14031369): No files, no impossibilities so far.
Makefile.o: src
src: src.o
#  Implicit/static pattern stem: 'src'
src.o:
#  Implicit/static pattern stem: 'src'
# @ := src.o
# * := src
# < := src.o
obj/foo.o: src/foo.c
# + := src/foo.c
# < := src/foo.c
# ^ := src/foo.c
# ? := src/foo.c
src/foo.c:
```

If we now redefine `Y` in that way: `Y = $(patsubst obj/%.o,src/%.c,$1)`, no circular dependency occurs, because `make` doesn't even try to apply the implicit rule `Makefile:Makefile.o`

```
make --print-data-base | grep src
OBJECTS executed for obj/foo.o - [src/foo.c]
Y = $(patsubst obj/%.o,src/%.c,$1)
# src (device 64769, inode 14031369): No files, no impossibilities so far.
obj/foo.o: src/foo.c
# + := src/foo.c
# < := src/foo.c
# ^ := src/foo.c
# ? := src/foo.c
src/foo.c:
```

When does `make` create the implicit rule `Makefile: Makefile.o`? What is the difference between the two different definitions of `Y`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing is, if you're going to use secondary expansion it's your responsibility to ensure that the result is correct.  In pattern rules that means your expansion has to handle all different values of `%`.  Here your problem is fundamentally that you're not properly handling values of `%` that don't contain slashes, but your target `%.o` will apply to all targets, not just targets in a subdirectory.  You need to fix your `sed` invocation.  One option would be:

```
Y = $(shell echo $1 | sed -e 's,^[^\/]*/,src/,' -e 's,\.o$$,.c,')
```

By adding the slash that substitution won't match a simple filename.  The replacement of the `.o` with `.c` will still happen however.

The reason you see this behavior is because make [tries to remake makefiles](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Remaking-Makefiles.html).  So it wants to build a target `Makefile`.  There is a built-in pattern rule that knows how to build an executable from an object file with the same name: `% : %.o`  The `Makefile` matches `%` so make tries to build `Makefile.o`.  It sees your pattern rule `%.o` and tries to apply it and in the second expansion it converts `Makefile.o` to `src` as discussed above.

So, in addition to the above there are other things you can consider:

If you have a sufficiently new version of make (and you define all your own rules) you can disable all built-in rules by adding:

```
MAKEFLAGS += -r
```

This is a good idea regardless since it allows make to run much faster by removing all built-in rules.

Second, you could change your pattern to be more specific so it will only match object files, like this:

```
obj/%.o: $$(call Y,$$@)
        ...
```

Now, this pattern rule will *only* match `.o` files in that subdirectory.

Comment: Thank you. I am aware of the fact that `make` attempts to remake the makefile and that latter matches the rule `% : %.o`. But why doesn't `make` try to remake the makefile if I use `Y = $(patsubst obj/%.o,src/%.c,$1)` as a prerequisite? The target does not change and hence, the the same built-in pattern rule should be triggered.

Comment: It does try that pattern rule.  However the `patsubst` won't match in this case (the pattern `obj/%.o` doesn't match the text `Makefile.o`) so the result of the substitution is the same as the input file.  That is, you get `Makefile.o : Makefile.o`.  There's a rule in pattern substitution that we always ignore any constructed target that we've already considered in this chain, so that is ignored and make keeps going.

Comment: Using the output of `-p` is not a good way to see what is happening.  That only tells you the _final result_ of all the checking is.  It doesn't tell you anything about what steps make took, and ignored, while coming up with that result.  If you want to know that, you have to use the `-d` option.  Be warned, there's a LOT of output.  But you'll see that make does consider it; it will say _Looking for a rule with intermediate file 'Makefile.o'._ followed by _Trying pattern rule with stem 'Makefile'._ and _Trying implicit prerequisite 'Makefile.o'._, which is then ignored.

Comment: In your sed example, the result of the sed operation is not `Makefile.o`, but `src`.  That's what I was trying to say above, about the fact that your sed operation is wrong: it mishandles filenames that don't have directories.  So the result of that is `Makefile.o : src`, and `src` _does_ exist (it's a directory in your environment obviously) so this _does_ match and make tries to use this rule.